# How can website server recognize incoming Tor or VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, proxy, tor, server

I was trying to signup for a service provided by a website using Tor, the website prevented me and asked me to disable my proxy settings, he noticed me with the following:

Our checks indicate that you are connecting through a proxy at the moment. Please disable your proxy settings first and then try again. Thank you!

Then I tried a VPN connection with normal browser without any proxy settings, but the website still gives me the same notice.

My question is:

1- How can the website server detect my anonymity-based connection (Tor or VPN), what is the interpretation?

2- Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: While the question is phrased differently, the first answer applies here. Because it's all publicly known. VPNs too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways I know is based on checking IP against a known list.

http://www.gohacking.com/detect-web-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

They could check the source the incoming traffic with a **public list** of Tor network.

But if you want to actually bypass there firewall you could do the following:

1. Use Tor and exit through a VPN. Keep in mind to use fake info or a public VPN.
2. Ask Tor project to give you an unlisted Tor exit node. (They always have a few for guys from China ;) )